# ERROR: Unable to retrieve device list

Tags: trigger.io

I get the following error when I try to user Target IO to run my application. I'm using Windows 7, 64-bit.

```
[INFO] Installing app on device: is it connected?
[INFO] connect: No error
[INFO] usbmuxd_get_device_list: error opening socket!
[INFO] ERROR: Unable to retrieve device list!
I get the following messages when I try to install my application.
[ERROR] Failed when running C:\...win-ios-install.exe: connect: No error

usbmuxd_get_device_list: error opening socket!
ERROR: Unable to retrieve device list!
```

Anyone have this error? Any ideas how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you email support@trigger.io with the whole traceback in the Toolkit console with the 'show debug output' box checked? What device are you trying to run on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have iTunes installed. The documentation is here: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tools/ios-windows.html#setting-up-forge-to-run-ios-apps

I got the answer from the tigger.io IRC from mib_9fc0ff. Thanks mib_9fc0ff and Amir.